# dynamically include return type dynamically using reflection in c#?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a requirement of invoke a function using reflection in c#.
The following code works fine for the function which have return data type sqldatareader.

```
 public override void Testmethod()
   {
        SqlDataReader Reader = (SqlDataReader)method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type),new object[] {arr});
   }
```

But now i need to mention the return type also dynamically and depends up on that i need to invoke the function.

how can i specify the return type dynamically?

Comment: not working. getting error The type or namespace name 'returnType' could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the return type of the method by

```
Type returnType = method.ReturnType;
```

Then you can compare the type, invoke the method you want and convert it's return type to the type known in compile-time (in this example, `SqlDataReader`)

```
if (returnType == typeof(SqlDataReader))
{
    SqlDataReader Reader = (SqlDataReader)method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type),new object[] {arr});
}
```

Do the same for other cases

```
else if (returnType == typeof(string))
{
    // invoke some other method and convert it's return type to a string ...
}
```

Comment: I tried `Type returnType = method.ReturnType;
                    SqlDataReader Reader = (returnType)method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), new object[] { arr });`  getting error The type or namespace name 'returnType' could not be found

Comment: @user833985 you can not cast to an unknown type at compile-time. you can use the `returnType` to test if it matches a type known at compile time and cast to that type. Updating my answer with an example